# How to ensure that a table has only a single record with Is_Deleted = 0 per Customer_Number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with these columns:

```
ID (int)
Customer_Number (int)
Is_Deleted (bit)
Details (nvarchar)
```

I need to create a trigger for the table which is going to prevent update of a row when trying to change `Is_Deleted` column from 'true' to 'false' while already having another different existing row with the same customer number and a false value on `Is_Deleted` (I can't allow two rows with the same customer number with `false` value in the `Is_Deleted` column).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No triggers.

```
create unique index t_ix_Customer_Number_Is_Deleted_0 
on t (Customer_Number) 
where Is_Deleted = 0
```

---

```
insert into t (ID,Customer_Number,Is_Deleted) values (1,1,1),(2,1,0),(3,1,1),(4,1,1)
```

> (4 row(s) affected)

```
update t set Is_Deleted = 0 where ID = 1
```

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 5
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.t' with unique index 't_ix_Customer_Number_Is_Deleted_0'.
>   The duplicate key value is (1).
>   The statement has been terminated.